# CGGradient in an CGPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Is it possible to draw a gradient in a path on the iPhone?

I'm looking for a replacement of the mac os x method

```
-(void)drawInBezierPath:(NSBezierPath *)path relativeCenterPosition:(NSPoint)relativeCenterPosition of NSGradient.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think something like this will work:

```
CGContextSaveGState(c);
CGContextAddPath(c, path);
CGContextClip(c)

// make a gradient
CGColorRef colors[] = { topColor, bottomColor };
CFArrayRef colorsArr = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void**)colors, sizeof(colors) / sizeof(CGColorRef), &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colorsArr, NULL);
CFRelease(colorSpace);
CFRelease(colorsArr);

//  Draw a linear gradient from top to bottom
CGPoint start = ...
CGPoint end = ...
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(c, gradient, start, end, 0);

CFRelease(gradient);
CGContextRestoreGState(c);
```

Comment: Thx a lot Todd!

I already had the same code, but I forgot the CGContextClip after the CGContextAddPath ....

Comment: I'm trying to understand this code but "colors" is declared twice with different types.  I'm not sure which one was being used in the subsequent calls.

Comment: progrmr, it's typo, should be:  

    CGColorRef colorRef[] = { topColor, bottomColor };
    CFArrayRef colors = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void**)colorRef, sizeof(colorRef) / sizeof(CGColorRef), &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

Comment: Is there anything else missing from this code? I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: Addendum: I posted my non-working code to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799882/clipping-a-cggradient-to-a-cgpath

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so if I understand your question.  It is a bit involved but here is a good example of doing it:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/drawing-gloss-gradients-in-coregraphics.html

This is done with Cocoa and not Cocoa Touch but it translates with everything bu NSColor.  You have to use UIColor instead.  Basically, you have to create a gradient function and then use:

```
CGShadingCreateAxial()
```

to determine the value of your gradient.

Or are you wanting to have a line with a gradient?