# Gradient instead of solid color for border on UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, button, border, gradient

I've seen tutorials on how to use a CAGradientLayer to make a button with a gradient background.  How would one go about using a gradient for the 'border color'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably subclass the button and draw a custom border in `-drawRect:`.

Comment: I agree about -drawRect - some tutorials I've seen do that.  Mostly, I'm looking for specifics on what the drawing code would look like that would mimic the border in the base UIButton class, but allow use of a gradient rather than simply a solid color.  I imagine the solid color is easy to do with a path and a stroke width using simple CG drawing calls.  My guess is the answer would have to do with a CAGradientLayer and somehow using the equivalent of the built-in border as a clipping mask.  Anyone have any direction on how to do something like that (or other/better approaches)?

Comment: Perhaps you could use this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563303/cggradient-in-an-cgpath) to fill a `CGPath` with a `CGGradient`?

Comment: Awesome - thanks.  When I searched to see if the question had already been answered I just didn't abstract it away to just that part of it - I was looking only for a full button solution.  Baby steps :)

If/when I get some time I'll get a working sample put together on github and throw a link up here.  For now, this answers my question.  Thanks again.