# How do i draw gloss inside a UIView using coregraphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I've spent hours now, unsucessfully trying to figure this out. I've never been good at coregrpahics so I'm asking for your help here.

I want to draw gloss inside a UIView. This is the type of gloss I want:

http://mos.futurenet.com/techradar/classifications/gadgets/phones/mobile-phones/iPhone/iphone4_2up_front_side-420-90.jpg

So in a triangle shape, but the white fading out as it goes down.

How do i do this using coregraphics? I really don't want to resort to just using an image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563303/cggradient-in-an-cgpath

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CGGradientRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html) docs.

You need to set a clip path on the `CGContextRef` if you want a triangle shape (add a path, and clip).