# How to draw a highlighter line using core-graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

I want to develop a iPhone app that supports highlighter drawing, similar to the following image:

[image]

I have tried `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`, but I don't believe that it can achieve this effect.
How can I do that on the iPhone using `core-graphics`?
Thanks!!

Comment: You should use a path and a gradient.
This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563303/cggradient-in-an-cgpath


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563303/cggradient-in-an-cgpath

Comment: try to use Attributed String, it will help you

Comment: I don't do anything about NSAttributedString..